# Javascript: Use "new Function()" to run code in a string and have it access class definitions

Tags: javascript, function, class, scope, eval

My actual code is dense, so I'm trying to reduce this to a minimal example.

I have MainUI.js which contains:

```
var MainUI = function(){
  'use strict';
  
  var singleton = null;

  class MainUI {
    makeSomethingHappen(){
      console.log("MAGIC!");
    }
  }

  return {
    getSingleton: function(){
      if (singleton == null) singleton = new MainUI();

      return singleton;
    }
  };
}();
```

Then I have test.js which contains:

```
function test(code){
  var uis = MainUI.getSingleton();

  retValue = new Function("ui", "use strict'" + code)(uis);
}
```

This is all run from index.html which contains:

```
<html>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="MainUI.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>

  <body onload="test('ui.makeSomethingHappen();');">
  </body>
</html>
```

But when I call

```
test("ui.makeSomethingHappen();");
```

or even

```
test("console.log('NARF!');");
```

I get an exception with the message

```
MainUI is not defined
```

The singleton accessor and the MainUI works in all my code outside of "new Function()", so I know it's working (even if I made typographical error producing the minimal test).

So I'm hoping someone can tell me how I can give the code inside the Function access to the class definitions outside.

Comment: the function constructor doesn't have access to the local variable. It executes code in the global scope. Why even use the function constructor here, though? Why not pass a callback?

Comment: I pass the variable in as an argument to the function call: "(uis)". I also don't understand how variable access would explain the class definition error. Could you explain how a callback would address my case?

Comment: If you pass in `(ui) => ui.doSomething()` as a callback and inside `test` you call `callback(mainUI)` you'd not need to muck around with trying to construct valid JS code - you'd get full tool support for the callback, too, including syntax highlighting, linting, refactoring from your editor, etc.

Comment: This was only a minimal example. I won't know what the code is at compile time because it will be fed in as text from an external source. That's why I'm passing in useful class instances for the code to use.

Comment: Based on the minimal code you've shown, the problem isn't with `new Function()` it's with `var uis = MainUI.getSingleton();` because that's where `MainUI` is referenced and your error talks about ***M***ainUI. The `new Function` refers to the string `"mainUI"`

Comment: Please note the difference between mainUI and MainUI

Comment: @Thakkie `mainUI` with lowercase is only used in the function constructor and it's a parameter. It doesn't matter what it's called. The `MainUI` variable (upper case) is completely different.

Comment: Ha! Anyone care to add clarification to the downvote? Would happily make changes to the question if I knew what the concern was :)

Comment: For the sake of disambiguation, I renamed "mainUI" in my actual code and re-ran it. The error is identical. I will now edit the original question to reflect this.

Comment: *Then I have test.js which contains:* <-- How are you referencing `MainUI.js` in this file? And, if you pull this `var uis = MainUI.getSingleton();` out of the function and try to execute it directly in `test.js`, will it run sucessfully?

Comment: @ScottMarcus Please see edit of question regarding index.html. As to using MainUI.getSingleton(), it is executed directly in test.js. The result of the call "uis" is passed as an argument to the Function call. MainUI.getSingleton() and all the related functions on the class definition work perfectly in all other code.

Comment: You're comment isn't clear. Have you tried MOVING `var uis = MainUI.getSingleton();` out of the `test` function to see if it runs without an error?

Comment: Yes, it is used in several other places entirely unrelated to this particular function. The error occurs only when the new Function is called. If I comment out the "new Function" line, then there is no error.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Nope, you were right, with all the work I've been doing I neglected to add the <script> tag for MainUI.js. I got caught out because I put the MainUI.getSingleton() call in the same try/catch as the new Function() call so I assumed it was coming from the function call. Could you add an answer, something like "MAKE DAMNED SURE YOU'VE INCLUDED THE DAMNED .JS FILE. YES, THAT MEANS YOU ACTUALLY HAVE TO GO AND LOOK, YA SMUG IDIOT!" so I can accept it as the answer :D

Comment: I've added an answer, but was more diplomatic about it than your suggestion! Good luck!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make sure that the `MainUI.js` `script` is referenced correctly and that it is referenced prior to the `test.js` `script` that will use it.